# Unable to get AJAX submission to work to update post_content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm having some issues with my AJAX form submission and I can't seem to figure out why, below I will be explaining all the steps that I will be taking to attempt to submit the form.

**The scripts are enqueued [WORKS]**: Ensures that the file holding the ajax request is loaded which it is.

```
function enqueue_scripts()
{
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_register_script('profile_edit_submit', content_url() . '/mu-plugins/fleishmanhillard/scripts/frontend-profile-edit.js', ['jquery'], '', true);
        wp_localize_script( 'profile_edit_submit', 'profile_edit', [
            // This will generate the admin URL that we can use on the front-end of our website
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            // Pass in a custom nonce name for JS
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('update_profile_validation'),
        ]);
        wp_enqueue_script('profile_edit_submit');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

**This updates the post ID's post_content** [**WORKS**]: On submission, it updates the database content of the right ID.

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "post") {

    // @todo: Make sure that the account is associated with the logged in account on profile edits

    // If profile isn't empty, continue
    if (!empty($profile)) {

        // Grab the content submitted
        // @todo: Figure out how to set the $_POST request to a function
        $post_content = $_POST['content'];

        wp_update_post([
            'ID' => $profile->get_id(),
            'post_content' => $post_content,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**HTML [WORKS]**:

```
<form action="" id="profile_update" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="content" id="post_content" class="required">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
    <button type="submit"><?= 'Update Post' ?></button>
</form>
```

---

**PROBLEM**: So the submission works but it refreshes the page on submit, but I'd like to move forward with an AJAX submission but I don't know where to begin.. here is what I have, but it's not working correctly.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function($) {
        $('.profile_update').on('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: profile_edit.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

When I submit the form, it updates the database and also changes the server request from GET to POST.

Comment: You are not cancelling the form submission. you have a class selector, not an id... form  click, don't you want submit??

Comment: @epascarello, do you mean that button type needs to be a button instead of submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to change the javascript.

```
(function ($) {
    $(function($) {
        $('#profile_update').on('submit', function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: profile_edit.ajaxurl,
                data: $('#profile_update').serialize();
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Let me attempt this @He Zhi Yong, is the button type a button or submit type?

Answer (score -1):

change the html this way

```
<form action=""  method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="content" id="post_content" class="required">
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
   <button type="button" id="profile_update"><?= 'Update Post' ?></button>
</form>
```

you are selecting a CSS class by using `.` in jQuery you need to use `#`
it should be

```
$('#profile_update')
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work on my end - When I click the submit button now, it does nothing.